# what are the Different ways of creating site collection template

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to create a site collection template and this should be used for creating new site collections from central admin.

is there any way to build the template other than using visual studio import SharePoint solution package option?

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: what is version of sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

When you `save as template` it scope to site and in order to globally deployment you need to import into Visual studio and change it from **Site/ web** to **Global**.

Another workaround mentioned by the ToddKnit, i think is good. here are few steps.

- Save the site collection as template.
- Now go to the solution gallery and download the newly created template.
- Now create a new site collection from central admin. This time, for site collection's template selection....click on custom and `Select template later`.
- Now browse to the url of newly created site collection. It will ask the Template selection.
- On this page click on Solution Gallery, and upload the template you download on previous steps.
- After activating, go back to site collection url and you will see new template under the custom tab.

[Creating a Site Collection with a custom Site Template](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=218)